# Matching Column Data from 2 mismatched worksheets, then automatically line the data up, adding blank rows when necessary

Tags: excel, match

I have an estimating program for the construction industry that will convert it's reports to excel.

I would like to compare the product type from the original estimate in **Column A** and compare it to the product type in **Column A** of a revised estimate in a seperate worksheet. The columns for the two worksheets won't necessarily have the same number of rows.  Some products in worksheet 1 won't be in worksheet 2, and vice versa.

I would like to compare the two and add rows where necessary so that I can use a simple subtraction equation to determine how much material to add or subtract.

For example:
Column A in worksheet 1 has the folling 4 entries starting in row 1 (M, M2, MF2, and MPNL).  Column A in worksheet 2 has the following 3 entries starting with row 1 (M, M2,MPNL).

Entries that match need to be lined up with all the relative data in that row.  So the quantities for products M, and M2 would line up since they match in both rows.  In worksheet 1, the third entry is MF2.  Worksheet 2 doesn't have a MF2. I would like for excel to insert an entire row in worksheet number 2, this way, all the information from the MPNL row in worksheet 2 would bump down to row 4, where it would match up with the MPNL row from worksheet 1.  I need this function to work both ways from worksheet 1 and worksheet 2, as the data will be inconsistent.

I hope this makes sense.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Similar idea to this question perhaps - http://stackoverflow.com/q/14328896/53614 ?

Comment: Sample file / screenshot would be very much helpful! You may share either link in comments or better edit your question.

Comment: The first file is how it would import into Excel.  There are 3 pages, Revised Qtys, Base Qtys, and Total Change.  The end goal is to line up the rows and subract the Base Qty value in column C from the Revised Qty value in column C to come to a value showing how much of a particular material I need to add or delete from the project.

Comment: The second file shows the end result that I'm looking for.  I've highlighted for you reference the rows in the Base Qty sheet that have been imported from the Revised Qty sheet and vise versa.

Comment: [google](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_ss6iknh5sPejZBbHZseEMtbHc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: [google](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_ss6iknh5sPU1UzOW5jTHBhS2c/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you would need to compare the `revised quantities` with the `base quantities` of each product and then find the `change in quantity`.
 
If the above is correct then you could do the following (assumed your sheet names are `revised_sheet` and `base_sheet`):

1. Add another sheet in your WorkBook and name it something meaningful (say, `product_movements` for the sake of this answer)
2. Add all your Material ID and Material Description in `Column A` and `Column B` of this new sheet - `product_movements`.
3. Do a vlookup in Column C `=VLOOKUP(A2,revised_sheet!A:C,3,0)` (row 2 assumed) to get the revised quantity
4. Similarly, in Column D use the formula `=VLOOKUP(A2,base_sheet!A:C,3,0)` to get the Base Quantity.
5. In Column E you could do `=C2-D2` to get the Change of Quantity
6. Now you can add all sort of Conditional Formatting to highlight appropriate changes.

Note: If you want formula in column E to work you need to keep your Quantity Columns as number only.